# Recycler view instance is retained on screen rotation

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am using a UI-less fragment to hold the state of ViewModel class. The state of ViewModel class is retained as it is expected.
Retain fragment:

```
public class LoveMatchActivityRetainFragment extends Fragment {

private LoveMatchViewModel loveMatchViewModel;

@Inject
public LoveMatchActivityRetainFragment() {}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

public void retainViewModel(LoveMatchViewModel loveMatchViewModel) {
    Log.e("df", loveMatchViewModel + " ");
    this.loveMatchViewModel = loveMatchViewModel;
}

public LoveMatchViewModel getViewModel() {
    return this.loveMatchViewModel;
}

}
```

Activity class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("my_fragment") == null) {
        mLoveMatchActivityRetainFragment = new LoveMatchActivityRetainFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(mLoveMatchActivityRetainFragment, "my_fragment").commit();

    } else {
        mLoveMatchActivityRetainFragment = (LoveMatchActivityRetainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("my_fragment");
    }

    mLoveMatchActivityRetainFragment.getViewModel();

    if (mLoveMatchActivityRetainFragment.getViewModel() != null) mViewModel = mLoveMatchActivityRetainFragment.getViewModel();

    bindingRecyclerViewAdapter = new BindingRecyclerViewAdapter<>(null);
    mBinding.rcv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mBinding.rcv.setAdapter(bindingRecyclerViewAdapter);
    Log.e(debugTag, bindingRecyclerViewAdapter + " adapter");
}



@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    dismissDialog();
    mLoveMatchActivityRetainFragment.retainViewModel(mViewModel);
    mLoveMatchActivityRetainFragment = null;
}
```

I have a RecyclerView to populate a list of data. I initialize the RecyclerView inside `onCreate()` to get rid of 'No adapter attached, skipping layout' error. Also I have a function that as soon as I get data from network is called to populate the RecyclerView with the real data.

```
private void initializeRcView(final ArrayList<PetObj> data) {
    bindingRecyclerViewAdapter.setItems(data);
    Log.e(debugTag, this.bindingRecyclerViewAdapter + " adapter here: "+this);
    bindingRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

The first time activity loaded and I get data from network RecyclerView is populated as it is expected. The problem is when a rotate the screen. I 
logged the instances of Activity and RecyclerView adapter inside `onCreate()` and inside `initializeRcView()` methods. Both new instances are being created inside `onCreate()` each time, but inside `initializeRcView()` the instances remain the same always. I removed `setRetainInstance(true)` from the retained fragment and RecyclerView populated correctly on rotation change. Can anybody address the issue? Why instances remain the same inside `initializeRcView()`?